# How to display an Admob interstitial, after a page has loaded in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, admob

The interstitial works fine when displayed through a button press. I have tried OnAppearing, but it runs before the page is loaded on Android. It seems no matter what I do, even with delayed calls, the page display overrides the ad.

**IAdInterstitial_Droid**

```
using System;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Verse.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IAdInterstitial_Droid))]
namespace Verse.Droid
{
    public class IAdInterstitial_Droid : IAdInterstitial
    {
        InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

        public IAdInterstitial_Droid()
        {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context);
            interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; // Admob test ad
            LoadAd();
        }

        void LoadAd()
        {
            var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
        }

        public void ShowAd()
        {
            if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded)
                interstitialAd.Show();

            LoadAd();
        }
    }
}
```

**IAdInterstitial.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Verse
{
    interface IAdInterstitial
    {
        void ShowAd();
    }
}
```

**Show the ad**

```
IAdInterstitial adInterstitial = DependencyService.Get<IAdInterstitial>();
adInterstitial.ShowAd();
```

Comment: Would you post a demo so that we can test it for you?

Comment: Yeah, I updated the post. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on the project on and off, I finally solved the problem by using the MarcTron.Admob plugin, instead of my initial implementation.

[Here is a tutorial for the plugin](https://www.xamarinexpert.it/blog/admob-made-easy/)